# Getting ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Please how do I display the response from,this endpoint using the apex webservice make request when I try outputting the response I get the ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error. The api I am calling returns a string when I test on postman. Below is my PLSQL code.

```
  declare
j_string clob;

  begin
   j_string := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => 'http://localhost/api/public/cerificate', p_http_method => 'POST',
    p_body => '{
    "name": "Jonh West",
    "gender": "Male",
    "dob": "sep-02-1977",
    "occupation": "Trader",
    "address": "NO 33 Mudupe Street Ikeja Lagos",
    "mobile": "08131500000",
    "email": "johnwest@john.com",
    "kinName": "James West",
    "kinMobile": "08145600000",
    "kinEmail": "west2@western.com",
    "coverPlan": "BRONZE",
    "coverMedical": "20000",
    "coverPDisability": "30000",
    "coverTDisability": "15000",
    "coverDeath": "44000",
    "aPremiuum": "80000"
}');

dbms_output.put_line(j_string);

 end ;
```

This is the error I get:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 23
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

1. declare
2. j_string clob;
3. begin
4. j_string := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => 'http://localhost/api/public/cerificate', p_http_method => 'POST',

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line number indicates that the error is caused by the `dbms_output.put_line`. It is expecting a string but getting a clob value which could be the cause of the error. I would try the following:

```
dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr ( j_string, 4000, 1 ));
```

and see if that works.

On a side note, naming a variable ".._string" while it is actually a CLOB is confusing :)

Comment: Thanks, it was getting a Clob value response hence the error.